How to generate file in MEDIA_ROOT in Django?
In my view I have a function that generates a file but does not return anything. I want the file to be generated in a specific folder in MEDIA_ROOT and saved in my models but I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing it. Here is the relevant section of my view:
writer = get_writer(output_format, output_dir)
This function generates a file in the stated directory. I want to save it to a specific directory relevant to my MEDIA_ROOT.
Here is the relevant section of my settings.py file:
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

The destination directory, for example, can be media/destination_directory but I'm not sure how to write the path relative to MEDIA_ROOT

You can use the os.path to construct file paths that are relative to your MEDIA_ROOT, so an example:
import os
from django.conf import settings

# ........

# Construct the destination path relative to MEDIA_ROOT
destination_directory = 'destination_directory'
destination_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, destination_directory, 'generated_file')

# Ensure the directory exists, create it if necessary
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination_path), exist_ok=True)

# Save the generated file to the destination path
with open(destination_path, 'wb') as f:
    writer.write(f)

# .........

Also, make sure that the destination_directory directory exists before you try to save the file by using os.makedirs(). The exist_ok=True argument ensures that no error is raised if the directory already exists.
